# How to print the letter of a certain string that the user wants

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have a question. I want to create a program that ask the user for a number between 1 and 26. Then use this response to print the corresponding letter of the alphabet (a is the 1st letter, b is the 2nd letter, z is the 26th letter, etc). If there is an IndexError, print ("Your number is out of range"). For all other errors, print("Something else occurred").

Right now I have this:

```
try:
    theAlphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    alphabet=input("Give me a number between 1 and 26.")
    print(len(theAlphabet)

except IndexError:
    print("Your number is out of range")
except: 
    print("Something else occurred")
```

I dont know what to do after the `print(len(theAlphabet)` part.

Comment: `print(theAlphabet[int(alphabet)])`?

Comment: `theAlphabet[int(alphabet)]`

Comment: Keep in mind indexing is `0` based. So you will need to adjust the user's input if you want `a` to correspond to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(chr(ord("a")+alphabet))
```

ord("a") gives you the ASCII value of the letter "a". Then you can add the number. chr(x) gives you the ASCII character for a value. Note that this is not checking for errors on the range, but it's probably best to do that another way.

Comment: So ord("a") gives you the ASCII value of the letter "a". Then you can add the number. chr(x) gives you the ASCII character for a value. But my way is not checking for errors on the range.

Comment: Why don't you add your comment onto your post?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the string with an index, but you will need to convert the user input to an interger using `int()` and also reduce the value by 1.

```
try:
    theAlphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    alphabet=input("Give me a number between 1 and 26: ")
    print(len(theAlphabet))
    print(theAlphabet[int(alphabet)-1])

except IndexError:
    print("Your number is out of range")
except: 
    print("Something else occurred")
```

Comment: print(len(theAlphabet) should be int(alphabet).

Comment: the `print(len(theAlphabet))` can be dropped completely, in all honesty. The line of `print(theAlphabet[int(alphabet)-1])` does the work of selecting the correct letter.